# SQL - Find the horses that have run at ONLY 1 specific track

Tags: sql

I have some horse data in a table and am practicing SQL while following my hobby.  I would like to find an elegant way to solve this problem.  Right now I have this convoluted way of getting the answer but I know there HAS to be an easier way.

Description:

I'll make it really simple (Assume these 8 rows are the entire table).  I have a table with 4 columns.  HORSE_ID, NAME, TRACK, Date

A horse might run at one track or many different tracks.  The end goal is to find what only the horses who have ran/campaigned at only one specific track....in this case, I want to see the horses that have run all their races at SA (Santa Anita)

```
HORSE_ID     NAME       TRACK      DATE 
1           JUSTIFY     SA         FEB-2018
2           JUSTIFY     PIM        MAY-2018
3           JUSTIFY     BEL        JUN-2018
4           KANTHAKA    SA         DEC-2017
5           KANTHAKA    SA         JAN-2018
7           THREE RULES GP         JUL-2016
8           DABSTER     SA         JAN-2018
```

So if I ran this query with this data, the only horses I would expect to see are KANTHAKA, and DABSTER because they are the only horses that only ran all their races at Santa Anita track.  So say next month KANTHAKA ran at ANOTHER DIFFERENT track, then the next time the query was run, only DABSTER would show up.

Does this make sense?

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow; please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to show us what you've tried, because that context is very helpful in knowing how to frame an answer that will be the most helpful to you

Comment: You may want to look at `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: It's funny how often people forget to give the name of the table, which makes it hard to compare answers because everyone has to invent a name for the table!  The 'horse ID' column is odd, too, because it doesn't identify the horse; it identifies a horse that ran on a track on a date.

Comment: John you are 100% right. I have to rethink that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MIN(TRACK) = MAX(TRACK);
```

Writing the `HAVING` clause as above is preferable to writing `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TRACK) = 1`.  The reason for this is that the above query can make use of an index on `(NAME, TRACK)`.

If in addition you wish to restrict to a single track, then we can try:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MIN(TRACK) = MAX(TRACK) AND MIN(TRACK) = 'SA';
```

Comment: This is great Tim and does what I wanted!  In addition to providing all horses that have run at one single track (your first query).  The second one let's me get a filtered list by track (in this case SA).  Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a subquery requesting the count of distinct tracks to be 1 using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT DISTINCT` and then select those `WHERE` the track is `'SA'`:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM 
      (SELECT NAME, MIN(TRACK) as TRACK
      FROM HORSES
      GROUP BY 1
      HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT TRACK) = 1) horses_one_race
WHERE 
      TRACK = 'SA'
```